# Calculate two chi-squared distribution r.v.s' covariance

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, covariance

$X_1,...,X_n\sim N(0,\theta)$, define:
$$
V= \frac{(n-2)\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2+(n\bar{X})^2}{n(n-1)}
$$

I realized that $Y=\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i}^{2} \sim \theta \chi^{2}(n), \quad Z= \bar{X}^{2} \sim \frac{\theta}{n} \chi^{2}(1)$, then the question can be simplified:
$$
Cov(V)=\frac{(n-2)^2}{(n(n-1))^2}Var(\theta Y) +\frac{n^4}{(n(n-1))^2)}Var(\frac{\theta}{n}Z)
+\frac{n^2(n-2)}{(n(n-1))^2}\cdot \theta \cdot \frac{\theta}{n}Cov(Y,Z).
$$

Two variances $Var(\theta Y)$ and $Var(\frac{\theta}{n}Z)$ are easy to calculate, but
I can't figure out how to calculate $Cov(Y,Z)$.

As I know, $Cov(Y,Z)=E(YZ)-E(Y)E(Z)$, it's easy to get $E(Y)E(Z)$, but what is troubling me
most is $E(YZ)$.

Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 1):

Sketch (almost solution):

$cov(\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i}^{2},  \bar{X}^2) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}  cov(X_{i}^{2},  \bar{X}^2) = n \cdot cov(X_{1}^{2},  \bar{X}^2)$ because $X_i$ are i.i.d.

Further $$cov(X_{1}^{2},  \bar{X}^2) = cov(X_{1}^{2},  (\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i}^{2} )^2 ) = cov(X_{1}^{2},  (\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i}^{2} )\cdot ( \sum_{j=1}^{n} X_{j}^{2} )) $$ $$= cov(X_{1}^{2},  \sum_{i,j=1}^{n} X_{i}^{2}X_j^2  ) = \sum_{i,j=1}^{n} cov(X_{1}^{2},  X_{i}^{2}X_j^2  )$$
Hence it's sufficient to find
$cov(X_{1}^{2},  X_{i}^{2}X_j^2  )$
If $i, j \ge 2$ then $cov(X_{1}^{2},  X_{i}^{2}X_j^2  ) = 0$ because $X_{1}^{2}$ and  $X_{i}^{2}X_j^2$ are independent. If $i=1, j>1$ (similarly $j=1<i$) we have $cov(X_{1}^{2},  X_{1}^{2}X_i^2  ) = EX_1^4 X_i^2 - EX_1^2 E(X_{1}^{2}X_i^2 ) = EX_1^4 EX_i^2 - EX_i^2 (EX_1^2)^2$ by independence.
If $i=j=1$ then it's easy to find $cov(X_{1}^{2},  X_{1}^{2}X_1^2  )$.

Comment: thanks for your reply! I think I get your idea, and I find some typos in your draft, like $\bar{X}^2$ should be $(\frac1n \sum_i X_i)^2$, not $(\sum_iX_i^2)^2$.

Comment: @Lucas Yes, it was a typo.